# What's wrong with my webpack file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

OK, let's say on `main.js`, I have this:

```
var topMenu = require('./menu.js');
console.log(topMenu.getCount()); // 1
topMenu.increment();
console.log(topMenu.getCount()); // 2
```

and on `menu.js`, I have this:

```
exports.currentTab = 0;

var count = 1;
exports.increment = function() { count++; };
exports.getCount = function() { return count; };

exports.showSearch = function () {
    $(".about-box").removeClass("active");
    $(".tele-box").removeClass("active");
    $(".tuts-box").addClass("active");

    $(".search-div").toggle();

    if (!$(".search-div").is(":visible")) {
        $(".tuts-box").removeClass("active");
    }

    currentTab = 1;
}

module.exports = [
exports.onKeyPressing = document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
if (evt.keyCode == 49) {
    console.log("Open 1st box");
        showTeles();
    }
if (evt.keyCode == 50) {
    console.log("Open 2nd box");
        showSearch();
    }
if (evt.keyCode == 51) {
    console.log("Open 3rd box");
        showAbout();
    }
}

];
```

My `bundle.js` compiles correctly. That, I do know. However, open visiting the page, I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on line `console.log(topMenu.getCount()); // 1` in `main.js` (bundle.js since it compiled correctly...)

However, when I remove this and what's inside:

```
module.exports = [
    ...
];
```

that is found near the bottom of `menu.js`, then it works and I get:

```
1
2
```

as expected. What is wrong with my file and how do I fix it? Also, I'm probably defining `exports.showSearch()` wrong. In all, can you locate the errors I am making while making this file? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exports` is an alias to `module.exports`. So, when you assign an array to `module.exports` in this part:

```
module.exports = [
    ...
];
```

You are overriding (clearing) the value in `module.exports` and hence `exports`. So all of these assignments are lost:

```
exports.currentTab = 0;

exports.increment = function() { count++; };
exports.getCount = function() { return count; };

exports.showSearch = function () {
  // ...
}
```

And that's why you get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. There is no such function as `getCount()` attached to `exports` (and `topMenu`).

**Update**

I don't know what you want to achieve, but removing the assignment to `module.exports` **might** solve the problem:

```
exports.onKeyPressing = document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  // ...
}
```

Again, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Oh, I understand. What would be the required solution?

Comment: I got it working except the on key press is not working... I'll let you know if I find a solution..

Comment: I got it. Just had to change the bottom from `showAbout();` to  `exports.showAbout();` Thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this behavior is specific to CommonJS, not webpack.